# Bluefish Turns Belly-Up

Tags: 14.04, kernel, crash, bluefish

Earlier this afternoon I was using Bluefish Editor on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with no problem. After installing this afternoon's kernel patch (3.13.0-76-generic), even before rebooting, Bluefish will no longer launch. The first twice I saw the "Applicaton has crashed" alert; now I don't even see that. The only trace I can find is a single-line entry in `syslog`:

> kernel: [ 2947.945466] traps: bluefish[10388] trap int3 ip:7feb062cec13 sp:7fff52a723b0 error:0

I have reinstalled, then removed and reinstalled; what else should I try? I'm working with Bluefish 2.2.5 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should upvote or downvote with  that title...

Comment: Did you `apt purge bluefish; apt install bluefish`?

Comment: If the problem persists, it's probably a bug in Bluefish that *you should report.*

Comment: `apt purge` did not solve the problem; I shall file a bug forthwith.

Comment: What you could try: did you remove `~/.bluefish`? Possibly local files are corrupted.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That appears to have worked. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Please do.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax perfect, I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Corrupted local files

In many cases, when removing/reinstalling does not work, corrupted local files are the cause. Often these local files are in a hidden folder (starting with a dot) in your home directory.

In the case of `Bluefish`, just remove the folder `~/.bluefish`. That should work :)